# get method in JViewLegacy

Tags: php, joomla

I'm pretty new in Joomla and I am struggling with a method that seems to appear out of thin air.

The problem I am having is an empty variable when it is supposed to be filled by

```
$items = $this->get('Items');
```

It is located in the file `view.html.php` and the class name is

```
class guruViewguruauthor extends JViewLegacy {}
```

I am sorry in advance if this is a stupid question!!

Comment: If possible, please edit your question include any additional code that will help add context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a getItems method in your guruauthor model class found in your site models folder.

```
 $items = $this->get('Items');
```

retrieves the data from the model. If you dont have getItems defined in model or getItems sql is not defined properly you may get an empty object.

Check this link it may help you

https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.2:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part

A sample getItems method from one of my component

```
public function getItems($recursive = false)
    {
        if (!count($this->_items)) {

            // import Joomla Categories library
            //if you forget this -> Fatal error: Class 'JCategories' not found in ...
            jimport( 'joomla.application.categories' );

            $app = JFactory::getApplication();

            $options = array();
            $options['countItems'] = 20;

//$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);

            $categories = JCategories::getInstance('eventmanagement', $options);

            $this->_parent = $categories->get('root');

            if (is_object($this->_parent)) {
                $this->_items = $this->_parent->getChildren($recursive);
            }
            else {
                $this->_items = false;
            }
        }

        return $this->_items;
    }
```

This will return list of categories and in view I call this as

```
 $categories = $this->get('Items');
```